# WebClient.DownloadFile 404 errors with HTML characters in URI?

Tags: c#

I'm using the WebClient class to download files from a web site and have a couple of questions.

1. When the URIs have HTML characters in the URI path (eg http://foo.com/path1`&amp;`path2.pdf) I get 404 (not found) errors.  How can I prevent this?  I thought HTML characters were safe?
2. When the URIs represent a directory (eg http://foo.com/path) I get 403 (forbidden) errors.  I understand why this is occuring but how can I test my URI to see if it represents a directory with no index page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. HTML encoded characters are not safe for URLs. You need to URL encode them. If your data is stored html encoded, you'll want to use [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) to get to a properly formatted URL (i.e. `foo.com/page?foo=1&bar=2`. If you have special characters that must go in URLs, like ampersands that are not part of the query portion of the URL, you'll want to URL encode them. Use [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx)
2. You can't.

Comment: @Randolpho - I'm not sure why you're saying I need to encode them when the encoded characters are what's causing the error to begin with?

Comment: @eft: html encoding and url encoding are not the same thing; you want your characters to be url encoded for the url, now they are html decoded.